# When is async function promise resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have below code:

```
let func = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("two");
            resolve();
        }, 3000);
    })
};

let func2 = async () => {
    console.log("one");
    await func();
    console.log("three");
}

(async () => {
    await func2();
    console.log("main"); // This should never be executed
})()
```

Noticed `func2` never returns a value, the promise returned by `func2` should never be fullfilled in my opinion. Hence `console.log("main")` should never be executed. However it is executed after `console.log("three")`. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Noticed func2 never returns a value, the promise returned by func2 should never be fullfilled in my opinion.

That is not how async functions work.  Your func2 returns when it is done executing.  The return value of a function with no `return` statement is the specific value `undefined`.  So, `undefined` becomes the resolved value of the promise.  Remember, in Javascript, `undefined` is a specific value.  It's as if you did `return undefined` at the end of your function block.  So, since `undefined` is the return value, that becomes the resolved value of the `async` promise.

---

To fully cover all the bases, `async` functions always return a promise and that promise gets a resolved/rejected value one of these ways:

**1. When you explicitly `return` a value from the function.**  That becomes the resolved value of the promise that the `async` function returns.

```
async function test() {
    return "hello";
}

test().then(val => {
    console.log(val);      // "hello"
});
```

**2. When you throw an exception.**  The exception becomes the reject reason of the promise that the `async` function returns.

```
async function test() {
    throw new Error("ouch");
}

test().catch(err => {
    console.log(err);      // Shows error object with message "ouch"
});
```

**3. When you return another promise.**  That promise is chained to the one that the async function returns and the promise that the async function returns will follow the one you returned (resolve when it resolves with the same value or reject with the same reason).

```
async function test() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve("hi");
        }, 1000);
    });
}

test().then(val => {
    console.log(val);      // "hi"
});
```

**4. When you return nothing.** That is the same as in regular functions and it's equivalent to a `return undefined` at the end of the function block so the resolved value takes on the value of `undefined`.

So, this:

```
async function test() {
    console.log("hi");
}

test().then(val => {
    console.log(val);      // undefined
});
```

Works exactly the same as this:

```
async function test() {
    console.log("hi");
    return undefined;
}

test().then(val => {
    console.log(val);      // undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A function that does not explexitly return something, actually returns `undefined`:

```
function test() { }
console.log(test());
```

Its the same with async functions, they also resolve to `undefined` when no other value was returned.

Answer (score 1):

An `async` function doesn't need a return value in order to resolve. It is considered resolved when it finishes executing without an error.

If you `throw new Error()` inside of `func2`, `console.log("main")` will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't return from a function it implicitly returns a default value — normally undefined. So the promise returned by `func2` will still resolve when the function returns.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions):

> A function without a return statement will return a default value. In
>   the case of a constructor called with the new keyword, the default
>   value is the value of its this parameter. For all other functions, the
>   default return value is undefined.

You can see this in your code if you alter it to this:

```
(async () => {
    func2()
    .then(d => console.log(d));
})()
```